# Right aligned button is misaligned vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with header text and a button on the right.

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Set All Values</button>
    </div>
    <h4>Points Earned for Each Chapter</h4>
</div>
```

The code above is what I have currently but I have tried many variations. In all of them, the button is not vertically aligned with the text. (The image below includes the overlay when I hover over the element in the Elements pane of Chrome, in order to show vertical alignment.)

[image]

Searching existing questions on stackoverflow, I've found this question posted a number of times; however, I found no knowledgeable answers.

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the line-height of the heading and the height of the button differ.

With a `line-height: 1.9;` for the heading it should work:

```css
.page-header h4 {
   line-height: 1.9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Set All Values</button>
    </div>
    <h4>Points Earned for Each Chapter</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the grid to be mobile friendly and make everything inside vertically aligned.

```
    <div class="page-header vertical-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Text on the left</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Set All Values</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this CSS

```
.row > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .vertical-center .row {
     display: flex;
      align-items: center;
   }
   /*maybe create an id instead of  h1*/
   h1 {
     margin: 0;
   }
```